# Passing seed/Setting seed/ C within R code

Tags: c, r

I am making C within R codes.

In my C code I am using rand() function to generate random number.
The R-ext.pdf says that I have to set a seed using the commands;

```
  GetRNGstate();
  PutRNGstate();
```

Although I am using these commands above, I am still getting different values for the same seed. Could you give me any help?

The minimum example is:

In C:

```
# include <R.h>
# include <Rinternals.h>
# include <Rmath.h>
# include <R_ext/Linpack.h> 

 SEXP example(){

   SEXP output;
   GetRNGstate();
   PROTECT(output = allocVector(INTSXP, 1));
   INTEGER(output)[0] = rand() % 50;
   PutRNGstate();
   UNPROTECT(1);
   return(output);
 }
```

In R:

```
dyn.load("example.so")
## The following codes return different values at ever run 
set.seed(1)
.Call("example")
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

That is a logic error in your thinking -- you *correctly* set the seed, initialize the R RNG from code ... but then call the **system RNG** instead of the R RNG.

Replace `rand()` with `unif_rand()` (or `norm_rand()`) and you should be set.

[Rcpp](http://dirk.eddelbuettel.com/code/rcpp.html) makes all this easier and gives you vectorised access to draws from the various distribution function (but you can of course do all this by hand too in C if you prefer).

By using `cppFunction()` from [Rcpp](http://dirk.eddelbuettel.com/code/rcpp.html), we now also take care of `RNGScope` which in turn provides `GetRNGstate()` / `PutRNGstate()` (while older examples still show instantiation of `RNGScope`; adding it does no harm as it does an equivalent of reference counting).

So it really is a one-liner to define, auto-extend, compile, and load this:

```
R> cppFunction("double myrand() { return norm_rand(); }")
R> for (i in 1:5) { set.seed(42); cat(i, " -- ", myrand(), "\n") }
1  --  1.37096 
2  --  1.37096 
3  --  1.37096 
4  --  1.37096 
5  --  1.37096 
R>
```

whereas without the re-seeding we get

```
R> for (i in 1:5) { cat(i, " -- ", myrand(), "\n") }
1  --  -0.564698 
2  --  0.363128 
3  --  0.632863 
4  --  0.404268 
5  --  -0.106125 
R>
```

Lastly, if you *really* want you can of course continue to use `rand()` (but see the literature on its sucky performance) but then use **its seeding function** instead rather than R's.

Comment: One liner! really powerful!

Comment: Yes, though the `cppFunction()` does some magic behind the scenes to make that line work -- it does get expanded.  But for us to use, it is pretty close to magic ;-)

Comment: But I is it better to use sourceCpp (at least for debug purpose)?

Comment: They do about the same work based on a char string, or a filename.  For real work and real debugging I still build packages...  For tests either one is great.